# How can I identify all unsafe operators in Swift?

Tags: swift, unsafe, linter

I'm aware of the following Swift syntax forms which, when they fail, cause a runtime error / illegal instruction:

```
var x: Foo!     // implicit unsafe unwrap
x as! y         // unsafe downcast
optionalValue!  // explicit unsafe unwrap
```

I want to remove as many as possible of these unsafe expressions from my program, and replace them with safe alternatives.

To remove these unsafe expressions, I first need to identify them. My naive approach so far has been to search for `!`, and ignore all the false positives like logical negation. What more reliable ways exist? For example:

- Is there a comprehensive list of all Swift syntax forms which are unsafe? I'm guessing my list above is not comprehensive.
- Is there an Xcode or compiler flag to turn these operators into compiler warnings or compiler errors?
- Is there a linter I can run which will do this job?

Comment: @matt thanks - what is that regex? I don't known of a complete list of all syntax forms which are unsafe

Comment: Also @matt: I tried swiftlint, and it didn't identify these unsafe operators. It complained about a bunch of trivial syntactic problems, but no important semantic problems. Example: it doesn't complain about `URL(string: "")!`

Comment: Also it just sounds like with swiftlint you forgot to opt in to `force_unwrapping`.

Comment: I can confirm that SwiftLint does not complain on `let foo = Int("123")!`, even with `// swiftlint:enable force_unwrapping` or `// swiftlint:enable all`. I am not a regular user of that tool though, so I might be overlooking something.

Comment: @matt Are you sure that all unsafe operations in Swift follow that pattern? Considering that the list I gave of examples is probably not comprehensive? Force unwrapping is just one example of an unsafe operation

Comment: What level of assurance are you trying to reach? All array subscription operations are unsafe, for example. Are you willing to forgo those? *Technically*, every instantiation of a class, closure or protocol existential can crash if the system is out of memory. Further, dynamically dispatched function calls can create infinite (mutual) recursion that blows the stack.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica a list like that is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: For example, I just discovered `try!`, which is another example of a syntax form which is unsafe, but which is not in my list

Comment: @jameshfisher But are you now going to try to write Swift without array subscripting, dynamic memory allocation, or (potentially-recursing) dynamic method calls? It's not  practical, and Swift's the wrong tool for the job if that's what you're looking for

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica no, I'm not - what I'm looking to do is identify such unsafe operations, then either eyeball it to see whether it's safe, or otherwise, convert to safe operations / add runtime checks

Comment: @jameshfisher You can't add checks for out-of-memory, and dynamic dispatch makes it impossible (in the general case) to use static call graph analysis to prove there aren't any potentially recursive method call cycles. I would suggest trying to avoid array sub-scripting in most cases, and using a `susbcript(safe index: Int) -> Element?` which returns an optional.